# CreateWithInlinesView validation in form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

Does anyone know how to validate form when `CreateWithInlinesView`  from the Django Extra Views is used?

Surprisingly enough  `def clean(self)` and `def clean_name_of_the_field` methods don't work there. I have checked it on function based view , so that they really don't work in `CreateWithInlinesView`. I could still use validators and  `def clean()` in model, but I would prefer to do it in forms...

If you had any experience in `CreateWithInlinesView` validation  -please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is late but I also faced the same problem. I have just added a few things to help with understanding. This can be done in the views.
I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55575622/3183519)

```
class ModelCreate(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = models.Model
    inlines = [ModelInline]
    form_class = forms.ModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("app:related_name")

    def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
        self.object = form.save()
        """Write your extra code in here"""
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```